# PHP Variable Variable for loop

Tags: php

hey guys is this even possible to be done in php

```
<?php   
$sectorcount = $row_SectorCount['COUNT(*)'];
//number of rows in database
for ($i = 1; $i <= $sectorcount; $i++)
{
${spendingname . $i}= array();
${spendingpercent . $i} = array();
${spendingid . $i} = array();

mysql_select_db($database_conn2, $conn2);
$query_Spending = "SELECT CONCAT(spending.SectorID, spending.ExpenditureID) AS 'SpendingID',
expenditure.ExpenditureName, spending.SpendingPercent, spending.SectorID
FROM spending   
INNER JOIN expenditure ON spending.ExpenditureID = expenditure.ExpenditureID
WHERE spending.SectorID = ".$i;
$Spending = mysql_query($query_Spending, $conn2) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_Spending = mysql_num_rows($Spending);
while($row_Spending = mysql_fetch_assoc($Spending))
{
${spendingname.$i}[] = $row_Spending['ExpenditureName'];
${spendingpercent.$i}[] = $row_Spending['SpendingPercent'];
${spendingid.$i}[]= $row_Spending['SpendingID'];
}
mysql_free_result($Spending);
}
```

i was planning to use this here in this context. having an array to draw out the values using a where clause and display them individually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is what you are looking for:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {
    ${'name' . $i} = $i;
}

echo $name3;
```

**But you *should* just use an array:**

```
$name = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {
    $name[$i] = $i;
}

echo $name[3];
```

If you need an array in an array, go ahead and do that too.  If you need more nested arrays than that, you should probably be using a class somehow instead of all that array nesting.

Comment: thank you!! i want to try it on an array within an array like $name.$i = array (); then using database to draw the data out

Comment: @JervisChionh You should upvote answers you find useful.  You should also accept an answer to your question by clicking on the check mark.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: i have in sufficient rep ! i would love to do that

Comment: heyy levi what if i want something like that   $spendingname = array();

for($i=1; $i<=13; $i++)
 {
$spendingname[$i] = one,two,three;
 }

echo $spendingid[1];  
?>

Comment: @JervisChionh I'm confused by your code.  You use both `$spendingname` and `$spendingid`.

Comment: $spendingid is a composite primary key where else $spendingname is the name given to the spending

Answer (score 2):

First off, I second the suggestion to use an array instead. [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) are not meant to be used like this.

That said, it is possible by accessing `${$name.$i}`, or perhaps doing something like

```
$varname = $name.$i;
$$varname = 1; // or read from $$varname
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array. That's what they're there for.

Comment: what if i want to have an array within an array?

Comment: Then just do so. Nothing wrong with arrays in arrays in arrays in arrays in arrays.

Comment: in arrays in arrays. They are called [nested arrays](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/multidimensional_arrays.php).

Answer (score 1):

As Kolink said, **that is what an array is for!**

However, What you are asking can be achieved:

[Read More Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Basically,

```
<?php

for($i=0; $i<=13; $i++){

    $varname = "name" . $i;
    $$varname=$i;

}

echo $name1; // 1

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not give desired output 1 instead will give 13

What s the reason of doing like this. you can make `array` a access is later on use

```
 for($i=0; $i<=13; $i++)
 {
        $name[$i]=$i;
 }

      echo $name[1];                    *//it will echo 1
```