# string name out of vlaue of another string php

Tags: php, string

in PHP I have the following case:

```
<?php $anz1='3';$i='1';echo $anz.$i;?>
```

I don't know how to echo  $anz1 with the help of $i. I must do it this way, this is just an easy case, I need it for loops where it echos every $anz
Thanks in advance
I hope I could write it understable for you, my english is not the very best.

Comment: "Variabe Variables" is what PHP calls this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: In your question is $anz1 == $anzi where i = 1? So you want produce code with following output: anz2 for i = 2, anz3 for i = 3 and so on?

Comment: `echo ${'anz' . $i}` is going to be the pattern you need.

Comment: This has an example almost exactly like you'll need [PHP Variable Variable for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721127/php-variable-variable-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
$anz1='3';
$i='1';
echo ${'anz'.$i};
```

Output:

```
3
```